# Kafka consumer keeps consuming when node does not exist in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a dataflow as follows with 3 docker containers in a cluster setting. I use the docker-compose file from https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/rel/nifi-1.8.0/nifi-docker/docker-compose with nifi version 1.8.0

```
ConsumeKafka 1.0 -> CountText-> LogAttribute
```

When starting this dataflow, I saw they process fine.

When stopping and killing one node and the other by `docker stop` and `docker rm`, I see the committed offset(`CURRENT-OFFSET`) is still progressing, but I don't see the log of the stopped container(s) anymore

```
TOPIC  PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET LOG-END-OFFSET                         
events1 0          29379464          41973308         
events1 1          29393696          41974539      
events1 2          29402673          41983220
```

The information is from 
`./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group test_local_2019_01_17`

I'm very sure the container is not running at all by checking `docker ps -a`. 
There is also no other consumer because when stopping all containers, the committed offset is not progressing anymore

Is there anything I should check why the CUURENT-OFFSET is progressing?
What would bother me is I cannot see the log of the partition(s), and the offset is still committed and progressing, which would probably mean data loss

Comment: Are you sure that "current offset" is the same as "committed offset"? The current offset of the topic could be increasing if something is still producing data, where as the committed offset may not be changing if your NiFI cluster is stopped.

Comment: the current offset is the committed offset. I update the command that shows the information. Hours ago I also observed that when stopping a container, NiFi restarts the whole kafka consumer, but some offsets logging are missing, although after restarting the stopped container and wait until the data is processed. for example, offset 29379464 and 20 messages count is logged by the stopped container, and 29380964 and 20 messages count is logged by the other running container (same partition). But 29379864 with 20 messages count is not logged anywhere, which indicates data loss

Comment: Well if you have a 3 node cluster and kill one node, the partition that was being consumed on that node should be rebalanced to one of the other nodes, and then when you bring back the third node it should rebalance again

Comment: thought the same. but I tested two rounds and some offsets logging should be there but not in all the three containers. is there documentation or implementation that I could read more? maybe I ignore sth and make sth wrong